# Passing object of struct template as a function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, struct, parameters, constructor

I'm trying to create a function which takes an object of my struct template as an argument.

```
template <unsigned dim>
struct vec{
float d[dim];

template<typename ...T>
vec(T&&... args) : d{args...}{}
float operator[] (unsigned n) const { return d[n]; }

// ...
};
```

This code works fine on its own, but it starts to hassle when I want to create a function which takes an "vec" object as a parameter.

```
void asdf(vec<3> a){ ... }
```

When I create an instance of my struct as the parameter input it works fine:

```
asdf(vec<3>{5.f, 10.f, 3.f}); // Works fine
```

But when I try something like this my compiler won't buy it:

```
vec<3> test{5.f, 10.f, 3.f};
asdf(test); // error: cannot convert 'vec<3>' to 'float' in initialization
```

My IDE says the problem is in the constructor. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're missing a copy constructor (and probably assignment operator)

Comment: If the array member is public anyway, you can just ditch the constructor and let it be aggregate initialized.

Comment: You might also gain some insight from watching Josuttis' presentation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs - IIRC, this issue comes up there.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Good advice but until C++20 gets widely adopted, aggregates don't work well with `emplace` functions as they use `()` for object construction, not `{}`

Comment: @NathanOliver -And? There's no need to throw the entire book at someone who just tries to create small aggregates of fundamental types. I highly doubt the extra copy in container insertion is going to be a performance bottle neck or a major nuisance here.

Comment: As an aside note, wouldn't it be more appropriate to code that constructor as `template<typename ...T> vec(T&&... args) : d{std::forward<T>(args)...} {}`?

Comment: @NathanOliver I wasn't really sure what was causing the problem so I left in some perhaps irrelevant code. I apologize.

Comment: @AntonAdamson No worries, after looking at it some more, I think I know what the issue is and I've removed my comment

Comment: Item 26 (Avoid overloading on universal references) of Scott Meyers's Effective Modern C++ talks exactly about this issue. From that item's summary: 1) Overloading on universal references almost always leads to the universal reference overload being called more frequently than expected. 2) **Perfect-forwarding constructors are especially problematic, because they’re typically better matches than copy constructors for non-const lvalues.** P-f constructors are a more difficult case to see because they are overloads of a special member functions automatically generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to exclude the constructor template from overload set when being passed a `vec`. Otherwise it's an exact match and preferred over the copy constructor which takes a `const vec&` (then requires to add constness to be called).

E.g.

```
template<typename T1, typename ...T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T1>, vec>>* = nullptr>
vec(T1&& t, T&&... args) : d{std::forward<T1>(t), std::forward<T>(args)...}{}
```

As @NathanOliver suggested you might need to define the default constructor if you use the constructor template as the default constructor.

Comment: The OP will also need to add a default constructor if using this technique as the old way also allowed the constructor to act as a default constructor.  If that is desired.

Comment: Would this perhaps allow me to mess up and input non-float values?

Comment: @AntonAdamson It works as your original version. Yes non-float values could be passed, and they'll be converted to `float` when initializing the array.

Comment: @songyuanyao Great! Thank you.

Comment: @AntonAdamson Sorry my comment was not precise, for other types when converted to `float` most of them would cause *narrowing conversion* issue in list initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue here is that your

```
template<typename ...T>
vec(T&&... args) : d{args...}{}
```

is greedy and will be used in place of the built in copy constructor since `T&&` will resolve to a better match.  To fix this, you just need to add a copy constructor that is a better match then your template, and you can do that by adding

```
vec(vec&) = default; // for lvalues
vec(const vec&) = default; // for const lvalues
vec(vec&&) = default; // for rvalues
```

to you class which you can see working in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f0f6cf4f6b23d3f).

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting problems with this solution now when trying to return an vec parameter. Something like: auto(vec a){ return a; } doesn't work, I get the exact same error. What is going wrong?

Comment: @AntonAdamson I forgot to include the move constructor.  Answer and live example have been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Overload resolution is tricky.  A perfect match will be chosen before one that requires a conversion.

This template constructor is a perfect match for anything:

```
template<typename ...T> vec(T&&... args);
```

This copy constructor is a perfect match for *const vec* types, and in that case is a better match than the template (because all things equal, a non-template function is defined to be a better match.)

```
vec(vec const& other); // copy constructor
```

In your code, the copy constructor is implicitly declared by the compiler.

Now, when you do this:

```
vec<3> test{5.f, 10.f, 3.f};
asdf(test); // error
```

The problem is that you are creating a *non-const* "test" object, so overload resolution finds a perfect match with the templated constructor, but must do a "const conversion" to match the copy constructor (and the copy constructor is what you want to use.)  **Therefore, it selects the template function and fails.**

However, if you declare `test` as a *const* object, it will compile and work as you probably expect:

```
vec<3> const test{5.f, 10.f, 3.f}; // **** Notice, const now
asdf(test); // ok
```

What you really want to do is prevent the template constructor from dominating the copy constructor, even for const conversions, and that can be done in multiple ways.

- add constraints to the constructor to prevent it from matching `vec` objects
- overload the copy constructor with const and non-const versions

In c++20 the first approach is straight-forward.  Just add a `requires` clause to ensure that none of your arguments are of type `vec`:

```
template<typename ...T>
vec(T&&... args) requires (not (std::is_same_v<T, vec> && ...))
    : d{args...}{}
```

`std::enable_if` is another approach on older compilers or langauge levels.

Another way you can accomplish it is to have "two" copy constructors:

```
vec(vec const&) = default;
vec(vec & other) = default;
```

This covers both cases of *const* and *non-const* `vec` arguments.  Being non-templates, when passing a vec, one of them will match better than the template and every other type will still select the template.

It will still fail if you mix different sized vecs, though, but you probably don't want that anyway.  But if you do, you can add another template specifically for it:

```
// Only used when Size does not match "our size"
template<auto Size>
vec(vec<Size> const & other) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but why does the constructor even run in the first place? The object is already created, so why again?

Comment: @AntonAdamson because `asdf` takes its argument by value.